# Error: cannot communicate with function. Request rejected

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I am trying to link my firebase database to stripe connect through functions , when a user register to my platform it automatically create a seller inside stripe. Everything worked fine until last month, then out of nowhere I am facing this error.

Already contacted the firebase support, they can't find the cause of the error saying that they are working to find a solution , suggesting keeping an eye to the thread:
https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/125425924

Some people says it maybe linked to bad use of promises , btw I'm on Node 6

The function is split both on a trigger on the database and http request functions

here my index.js

```
exports.setPagamentiProprietario = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

    let IDProprietario = req.url.replace('/',''); 
    if(IDProprietario === null){
        return res.status(400).send(impacchettaInformazioni(err,"invalid user id","400"));
    }

    return admin.auth().getUser(IDProprietario).then(function(userRecord) {
        const email = userRecord.email;
        return funcPagamenti.registraProprietario(IDProprietario,email,admin.database()).then(function(data){
            return res.status(200).send(impacchettaInformazioni(data,"ok","200"));

        }).catch(err => {
            console.log("errore registrazione stripe" + err);
            return res.status(500).send(impacchettaInformazioni(err,"error","500"));
        })

    }).catch(err => {
        console.log("errore registrazione stripe" + err);
        return res.status(500).send(impacchettaInformazioni(err,"error","500"));
    })  
})


exports.proprietarioCreato = functions.database.ref("Proprietari/{IDPropietario}").onCreate(event =>{

    const IDProprietario = event.params.IDUProprietario;
    const proprietario = event.data;

    return admin.auth().getUser(IDProprietario).then(function(userRecord) {
        const email = userRecord.email;
        return funcPagamenti.registraProprietario(IDProprietario,proprietario,email,admin.database());

    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Erorre registrazione proprietario  STRIPE:", error);
    });

})
```

Here is my funcPagamenti.registraProprietario:

//Registra un proprietario su stripe

```
exports.registraProprietario = function(IDProprietario,proprietario,email,database) {

    return new Promise((res, rej) => {

        try{

            stripe.accounts.create({
                type: 'custom',
                country: 'IT',
                first_name: proprietario.Nome,
                last_name: proprietario.Cognome,
                email: email

            }, function(err, customer) {

                if(err !== null){
                    console.log(err);
                    return rej(err);
                }
                return database.ref('Proprietari').child(IDProprietario).update({"IDPagamenti":customer.id}).then(function(){
                    return res(custumer.id);
                }).catch(err => {
                    console.log(err);
                    console.log("Errore update proprietario" + err);
                    return rej(err);
                })

            });

        }catch(errore){
            console.log(err);
            return rej(errore);
        }

    })

}
```

I expect that stripe return the id of the vendor registered to the platform.

Instead i get:

Error: cannot communicate with function. Request rejected.

///**EDIT**

Actually it was my fault, I was calling the method with a wrong signature all along , since the compiler didn't gave me any warnings I was not able to detect it before, anyway here is the revision:

```
//Registra un proprietario per accettare i pagamenti
exports.setPagamentiProprietario = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

    let IDProprietario = req.url.replace('/',''); 
    if(IDProprietario === null){
        return res.status(400).send(impacchettaInformazioni(err,"invalid user id","400"));
    }

    return admin.auth().getUser(IDProprietario).then(function(userRecord) {

        return admin.database().ref("Proprietari").child(IDProprietario).once("value").then(snap => {
            const email = userRecord.email;

            return funcPagamenti.registraProprietario(req.connection.remoteAddress,IDProprietario,snap.val(),email,admin.database()).then(function(data){
                return res.status(200).send(impacchettaInformazioni(data,"ok","200"));

            }).catch(err => {
                console.log("errore query proprietario" + err);
                return res.status(500).send(impacchettaInformazioni(err,"error","500"));
            })

        }).catch(err => {
            console.log("errore registrazione stripe" + err);
            return res.status(500).send(impacchettaInformazioni(err,"err","500"));
        })  

    }).catch(err => {
        console.log("errore registrazione stripe" + err);
        return res.status(500).send(impacchettaInformazioni(err,"error","500"));
    })  
})
```

Comment: No change in your pricing plan? Stripe is not a Google service, therefore you need to be on a Firebase paid plan.

Comment: I am on blaze(pay as you go) , my mistake not including that

Comment: Hi, did you have time to look at the proposed solution below?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use a Promise instead of a callback function when calling the Stripe node.js API.

As said in the [documentation](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node#using-promises):

> Every method returns a chainable promise which can be used instead of
>   a regular callback

So you may change `funcPagamenti.registraProprietario` as follows:

```
exports.registraProprietario = function(
  IDProprietario,
  proprietario,
  email,
  database
) {
  let accountId;

  return stripe.accounts
    .create({
      type: 'custom',
      country: 'IT',
      first_name: proprietario.Nome,
      last_name: proprietario.Cognome,
      email: email
    })
    .then(account => {
      accountId = account.id;
      return database
        .ref('Proprietari')
        .child(IDProprietario)
        .update({ IDPagamenti: accountId });
    })
    .then(() => {
      return accountId;
    });
};
```